# Heap dump memory leak

Tags: java, memory, memory-leaks, garbage-collection, heap-memory

I have a problem with finding a root cause of memory leak. I see no suspicious things in heap dump.

I see that the most heap is being consumed by `byte[]` and `char[]` + `int[]`

[image: heap dump]

[image: heap dump retained2]

[image: heap dump1]

In Yourkit I see some tips that memory leak can be done by "Thread local variables":
[image: heap dump2]

[image: heap dump3]

In all threadLocals there are Encoders + Decoders - why? any reason?

please give an advice where to search for a problem.

In thread dump is see many Waiting Threads:
[image: thread dump]

Answer (score 2):

You have 23502 thread objects (java.lang.Thread) in your dump. This is far from normal. These thread are either sleeping (you are leaking threads) or dead (but some how referenced from live graph).

In former case reconsider your thread usage, in later pick a dead thread an use "path to root" action to identify leak root cause.

PS: Normally, for memory leak case you need to capture two heap dumps and analyze difference.

Comment: From the names of the threads shown in the dump, the problem seems to be the creation of an insane amount of thread pools with two threads each (and probably never even trying to shut them down)… Of course, creating tons of thread pools with little number of threads, is the opposite of how they are supposed to be used.